# Unsure why I got a downvote hours after my question was answered

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949172/call-to-sscanf-is-screwing-with-other-variables) that, in my opinion, adhered to all the rules of SO. It was answered within 15 minutes and I accepted the answer. At some point last night it was downvoted, and no comment was left. Can anyone shed some light on why I got a downvote?

I'm trying my hardest to maintain a positive question record in order to get certain badges, so any feedback would be great.

Edit: You guys can seriously stop with the downvotes. I get what I did wrong, and 8 downvotes seems a little excessive. As I said before, I'm trying to maintain a positive record and that's hard to do if I'm going to get downvoted into oblivion

Comment: It's just a pile of code with a "plz fix" attached to it.  I'm surprised it only got 1 downvote.

Comment: @Servy no it isn't. It's a short example that demonstrates the problem along with a statement of the problem. What would you have done to improve it?

Comment: Not sure.  UB due to misuse of sscanf format specifiers is far from an uncommon bug, and maybe someone thought that you should have spotted it yourself?  They would be right since scanf format documentation is easily available, but I would not downvote your question for it - there are far worse questions that need downvotes..

Comment: I didn't (and won't) downvote, but you could've narrowed the code down a bit, given that you *know* which line of code causes the problem. At the very least, anything before the declaration of `crc` and after the `sscanf()` call could be removed.

Comment: @ErikJohnson There nothing describing what the code *should* do, there's no indications of what you've done so far to diagnose the issue, what information you've found, you have a lot of unnecessary code that should be removed, and fundamentally this just isn't going to be something that will ever be useful to anyone else, ever.  And then of course there's the issue of doing your research.  I'm not faimilar with the topic but [it would seem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322349/?noredirect=1#comment340410_322349) you did not do your homework.

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks! I'm never sure how much code to include when asking a question. I see now now I could have shortened it!

Comment: [Tim lost his keys... AGAIN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)

Comment: @JustDoIt That was just what I needed. Gotta remember that one for next time I'm getting salty about a downvote

Comment: @whispers We ask for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You would probably do well to review that if you're confused about why it seems like we ask for all and minimal code at the same time.

Comment: No...  your not understanding.

Its what the users 'THINK' should be there.. full, minimal..etc..  You'll never make them ALL happy.. hence down votes.

Comment: @mason That's exactly what I thought I was dong :) But it definitely could have been made shorter, which I see now.

Comment: @whispers Fair enough. It IS difficult to make everyone happy, hence my question. If the question has been answered satisfactorily to the asker and the answerer, I don't see why people need to downvote it. But oh well

Comment: @ErikJohnson Because your question and answer are not solely between the asker and answerer. Stack Overflow is a resource of questions and answers that should be usable for more than just the person that asked it. Therefore questions should demonstrate only the minimal amount of code necessary that completely demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @ErikJohnson Remember that your post and it's answers are not just for you alone, they are for everyone who's in need of such information. So whether you got an answer or not, it's irrelevant for someone's right to downvote, there's no way we can know why it happened, but it did, so just move on

Comment: @ErikJohnson while it is hard to make everyone happy it is easy to make many people unhappy... If instead of "I have been pulling out my hair trying to debug this" you'd provided input inline in the post and removed all unrelated code (strtok/while/printf) you'd have much better post... Still likely to get downvotes for not reading documentation of `sscanf`, but at least it would be clear that you put more efforts than just copy-paste chunk of random code.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you might be getting "downvoted to oblivion"  but you're the one who opened the door in the first place by linking your question. *meta effect*

Comment: @JustDoIt can you please vote to delete my original question? I've learned from the experience and I just want to be rid of it at this point

Comment: I think that at this point, only high rep users(or only mods, not sure) can delete your question

Comment: @JustDoIt you're right, looks like you need 20000 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to break any rules in order to get downvoted, just about any reason someone has to dislike your post is grounds to downvote it.

So, if your post has a bunch of code in it that's not crucial to demonstrating the problem, people can down vote that.

If your code is formatted in such a way that it's difficult for people to read, they can down vote that.

Comment: It's hard to be fair when downvoting. Sure, these may be valid reasons. But it might be worth taking a look later on and see if the question got improved. On occasion, I even see reason to retract a close-vote. (Rarely but it happens.)

Comment: @RadLexus Would you say that the question has ben sufficiently improved by Paul Roub and myself that is is now valuable? I ask because I really want to maintain a positive record and it is difficult to please everyone

Comment: @ErikJohnson: looks okay, by my standards. Let's hope your downvoters revisit it.

Comment: @ErikJohnson  It's just a downvote.  It's not the end of the world

Comment: @SamIam I understand that. I want to know why it happened so I can improve the quality of my questions / answers.